# PHP email script not working after validation

Tags: php, html, email, contact-form

There must be thousands of questions asked about PHP email scripts but I still haven't found my answer. I looked on the php website but it didn't really help either.

Basically my script validates the inputs and displays error message accordingly but when I add the second part of the script to handle the sending of the email the page displays a 500 error. Here is my code. The email hasn't been set to the correct email at the moment but I know that's not the problem.

```
<?php include('includes/header.php'); 

$yourEmail = "hello@example.com";
$formSubject = "Message recieved from enquiry form";


if( isset( $_POST["submit"])) {

//Validate the data
function validateFormData( $formData ) {
    $formData = trim( stripslashes(htmlspecialchars( $formData )));
    return $formData; 
}


//check to see if inputs are empty
// create variables with form data
// wrap the data with our function

if( !$_POST['name']) {
    $nameError = "Please enter your name <br />";  
} else {
    $name = validateFormData( $_POST["name"]);
}
if( !$_POST['email'] || !preg_match("/^\S+@\S+$/", $email)) {
    $emailError = "Please enter a valid email address <br />";  
} else {
    $email = validateFormData( $_POST["email"]);
}                
if( !$_POST['enquiry']) {
    $enquiryError = "Please enter your enquiry <br />";  
} else {
    $enquiry = validateFormData( $_POST["enquiry"]);
}
```

Code Works fine up until this point;

```
//Check to see if submit is set
//Check to make sure errors don't exist
//Send the email
// Redirect user to success.html  


if ( isset( $_POST["submit"]) && (empty($emailError, $nameError, $enquiryError))) {

$to = $yourEmail;
$subject = $formSubject;  
$headers = 'From:'. $name . "\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '. $email . "\r\n".
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$body = 

'The person that contacted you was '.$name.'
Email: '.$email.'
URL: '.$url.'
Message: '.$enquiry.''.

mail($yourEmail, $formSubject, $body, $headers);



header("Location: success.html");


}
}

?>
```

This is the HTML form, which I'm sure is alright considering the PHP works up until a certain point and displays the error messages correctly. I know I have PHP_SELF which a lot of people say not to use but I want to to stay on the page if errors exist and only redirect if email has sent.

```
<form id="contactForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo   htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

<label for="name">Name&nbsp;<span class="asterisk">*</span></label> 
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>"tabindex="1"/>
<span class="error"><?php echo $nameError; ?></span>

<label for="email">Email&nbsp;<span class="asterisk">*</span></label> 
 <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" tabindex="2"/>
  <span class="error"><?php echo $emailError; ?></span>  
  <span class="error"><?php echo $emailValidError; ?></span>  

 <label for="url">Website</label> 
  <input type="url" name="url" id="url" value="<?php echo $url;?>" tabindex="3"/>


 <h3>Tell us about your project&nbsp;</h3><br />

 <textarea name="enquiry" id="enquiry" tabindex="4"><?php echo $enquiry;?></textarea>
   <span class="error"><?php echo $enquiryError; ?></span>  

   <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >Submit</button>

 </form>
```

Comment: Error 500, check your logs, and/or error reporting.

Comment: The `mail` function may even tell you that it sent the mail, but there's no guarantee that it will reach its destination.  Try using an SMTP library for PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
empty($emailError, $nameError, $enquiryError)
```

empty accepts only one param, you are passing it 3. Change the conditional to:

```
if( isset( $_POST["submit"]) && ( empty($emailError) && empty($nameError) && empty($enquiryError) ))
```

Or if you want to shorten that conditional a little

```
 $Errors = $emailError.$nameError.$enquiryError;
 if( isset( $_POST["submit"] ) &&  empty( $Errors ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is why there's an error. First syntax error and then  (empty($emailError, $nameError,    $enquiryError)) is not a good idea. I would do something like this:

```
 $err=0;
 if( !$_POST['name']) {
         $nameError = "Please enter your name <br />";  
         $err++;
       } else {
        $name = validateFormData( $_POST["name"]);
         $err++;
       }

 if( !$_POST['email'] || !preg_match("/^\S+@\S+$/", $email)) {
       $emailError = "Please enter a valid email address <br />"; 
       $err++; 
       } else {
        $email = validateFormData( $_POST["email"]);
  }        


 if( !$_POST['enquiry']) {
      $enquiryError = "Please enter your enquiry <br />";  
      $err++;
      } else {
      $enquiry = validateFormData( $_POST["enquiry"]);
    } 

   if ( isset( $_POST["submit"]) && $err==0) {
        //your code here//
        //and i would do like this//
        $result_mail_send = mail($yourEmail, $formSubject, $body, $headers);
        if($result_mail_send==true){
              //redirect to success
        }else{
              //redirect to fail//
        }

    }
```